# how to use more than one instance of google captcha on a page using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, recaptcha

I am trying to make use of google's CAPTCHA on two of my forms on a page

I have been able to implement the CAPTCHA on both forms on my page

But when i click form 1 it gives an error for form 2 **(because form 2 is empty on the same page)**

This is my implementation of the CAPTCHA

```
<script src='https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js'>
</script>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
function cap(){
    var captcha_response = grecaptcha.getResponse();
    if(captcha_response.length == 0) { // Captcha is not Passed
        alert("Please use capatcha below");
        return false;
    } else { // Captcha is Passed
        return true;
    }
}
// ]]>
</script> 


<form action="<?php echo 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>" method="post" onSubmit="alert('Your request has been received, we will get back to you shortly.');">
    <input name="name" type="text" placeholder="Your Name" required>
    <input name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    <input name="phone" type="number" placeholder="Phone" required>
    <input name="location" type="text" placeholder="Location" required>
    <input name="budget" type="text" placeholder="Budget Range" required>
    <textarea name="message" placeholder="Message Here..." required></textarea>
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LcR0EIUAAAAALqc0BtX8KhMa1_oeK14ssjFi7RG"></div>
    <button type="submit" onclick="return cap();" class="tran3s">Send Request</button>
</form>
```

I have tried to create to separate functions cap and caps, but i still have the same error

Please how can i use two instances of this CAPTCHA on a page on different forms without triggering each other?

Comment: Sorry to not provide useful feedback, but could you provide more source code, the current code only includes a single form.

Comment: its the same form

Comment: I see, so you're trying to run it on the same form in two seperate locations?

Comment: very correct,infact one is a popup and the other one directly on the page

Comment: Okay, I'm with you now.... Have you seen anything like [this tutorial](http://mycodde.blogspot.co.uk/2014/12/multiple-recaptcha-demo-same-page.html)?

Comment: please may i understand why my question is down voted, i feel most people just love to down vote a question

Comment: thanks JO3-W3B-D3V ill take a look at that

Comment: I know that feeling all too well, if it makes you feel any better, I upvoted your comment where you explained how one is a pop up... Etc.. In the spirit of kindness, I'll upvote your question so it's not negative! ;) ... Also no need to thank me, hope it helps!

Comment: yes cool cheers